# Page number in the margin and separator

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, titlesec

I want to produce this kind of header. 
[image]

My first attempt includes the use of fancyhdr package but still I can't figure out how it is possible to move the page number in the margin and put the | bold separator. 
Does anyone know if fancyhdr is capable of this kind of customization or should I look at titlesec – titleps packages?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, english]{book}
%
\usepackage{lipsum} % to produce dummy text
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily \itshape \thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily \itshape\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily \bfseries \thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize \rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
%
\chapter{Basic principles for multi camera systems}
    \lipsum[3-15] % dummy text
\section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[3-15] % dummy text
\subsection{Image processing}
    \lipsum[3] % dummy text
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You only need to give the page number a zero width. E.g. `\fancyhead[RO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-3mm}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{1mm}{1cm}} \sffamily \bfseries \thepage}}`. (The left side needs a mirror definition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops your comment crossed with my answer, sorry

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's the other way round: my comment crossed with your answer ;-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\leavevmode\smash{\llap{\sffamily \bfseries \thepage\ \rule[-1em]{5pt}{2em}}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leavevmode\smash{\rlap{\rule[-1em]{5pt}{2em}\ \sffamily \bfseries \thepage}}}
```

Comment: Dear David, is it possible to have the line and the page in the internal margin, instead of in the external? Thanks.

Comment: @lf_araujo yes of course just change LE and RO to LO and RE

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I couldn't explain properly. Changing LE to RO makes the pagenumber go inwards, it leaves the margin. What I meant is more like [this](http://imgur.com/a/xIO2y).

Comment: @lf_araujo the site doesn't really support new questions as comments in old answers, can you make an example and ask a question on site (as it is I can't relate that image to this answer or your comment:-)

Answer (score 0):

After the helpful comments above and a bit code manipulation, the final result is exactly what I was looking for. After all, fancyhdr can offer this kind of customization and I would like to share it here in case someone else need the final code to work towards something better...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, english]{book}
%
\usepackage{lipsum} % to produce dummy text
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily \itshape \thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily \itshape\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leavevmode\smash{\llap{\sffamily \bfseries \thepage\ ~\rule[-.5em]{2pt}{2em}} \leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leavevmode\smash{\rightmark ~ \rlap{~\rule[-.5em]{2pt}{2em}\ ~\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
%
\tableofcontents % you can comment this one...
\chapter{Dummy Chapter Title with Many Words}
    \lipsum[3-15] % dummy text
\section{Dummy Section Title with Many Words}
    \lipsum[3-15] % dummy text
\subsection{Dummy Subsection}
    \lipsum[3-5] % dummy text
\section{A Short Dummy Section}    
    \lipsum[3-10] % dummy text
%
\end{document}
```