# Pagenumber in marging

Tags: fancyhdr, pandoc

I would like to add a pagenumber style to my document, so that it is printed in the margin, but near the fancyhdr header as in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOhDG.jpg).

Mr. Carlisle solution in [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101452/93260) is the best I could find, but it places the number in the opposite side. His solution uses the following combination of commands:

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\leavevmode\smash{\llap{\sffamily \bfseries \thepage\ \rule[-1em]{5pt}{2em}}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leavevmode\smash{\rlap{\rule[-1em]{5pt}{2em}\ \sffamily \bfseries \thepage}}}
```

- How to make it look like the below?
- How to remove the bottom pagenumbers from all pages, I can't figure out how to remove them from the first page of each chapter.

[image]

Comment: A header have little sense in the page of a chapter (it is clear at the first glance where you are)  so why there are only the page number at the bottom. You can override this default behaviour a place de usual header/footers with `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\chapter{}`  but it is not a good idea.

Comment: About the opposite side, note the  options `[LE]` (left,even) and `[RO]` (right-ddd). The page numbers in the footer are removed id you make a `\fancyfoot{}`, for instance. Please run `texdoc fancyhdr` to see more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\rlap{\qquad \thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leavevmode\llap{\thepage\qquad}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ \spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ \spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\rlap{\qquad \thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leavevmode\llap{\thepage\qquad}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]